# Return String continuously - Data getting overwritten by ArrayList

Tags: java, javafx

Currently creating a tableview using JavaFX and came accross this problem where it would simply append the last element of the array (As all the other elements get overrwritten ..)

```
public  void companyTable() {
   for(CompanyData s: companydataList()){
       companyDataTableView.getItems().setAll(s);
   }
}
```

Where `companyDataList` is:

```
 private List<CompanyData> companydataList(){
        CompanyData company = new CompanyData("test",9,1);

        for(String i : sim.getCompanyNames()) {
           company.setPFCompanyName(i);
       }

       for(int j : sim.getCompanyValues()) {
           company.setPFShareValues(j);
       }
        List<CompanyData> companydata = new ArrayList<>();
        companydata.add(company);

        return companydata;
    }
```

The data gets added to this (Setters and getters of Strings)

```
 private final StringProperty PFCompanyName;
    private final IntegerProperty PFShareValues;

    public CompanyData(String CompanyName, int ShareValue, int ClosingPence) {
        this.PFCompanyName = new SimpleStringProperty(CompanyName);
        this.PFShareValues = new SimpleIntegerProperty(ShareValue);
    }

    public String getPFCompanyName() {
        return PFCompanyName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty PFCompanyNameProperty() {
        return PFCompanyName;
    }

    public void setPFCompanyName(String PFCompanyName) {
        this.PFCompanyName.set(PFCompanyName);
    }

    public int getPFShareValues(int j) {
        return PFShareValues.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty PFShareValuesProperty() {
        return PFShareValues;
    }

    public void setPFShareValues(int PFShareValues) {
        this.PFShareValues.set(PFShareValues);
    }
```

Currently the output is:

```
CompanyName             CompanyValue
Samsung                   1093
```

But what I desire is:

```
CompanyName             CompanyValue
Nokia                        3
Apple                        1
HTC                          9
Samsung                     1093
```

Comment: `getItems().setAll(s);` this implies it override all previous items. Isn't there an `add` or `append` method?

Comment: @RobCo It's just a regular `java.util.List` (or subtype thereof), so, yes, it has `add()`.

Comment: No, sadly there isn't an add or append method

Comment: @Zeionic sorry, what are you talking about? `TableView.getItems()` returns an `ObservableList`, which is a sub-interface of `java.util.List`. Of course it has an [`add()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-).

Comment: @James_D It returns a List yes, however in my `CompanyData` class it sets the String continuously (Till it's the last value) which then appends that String to the table.

Comment: @Zeionic have you tried replacing setAll with add?

Comment: @Novaterata Tried it just now and it  doesn't seem to work

Comment: Oh, also, what is your `companydatalist()` supposed to do?

Comment: Companydatalist is simply the setup (retrieving the data) from the arraylists and setting them in the `CompanyData` class.

Comment: But it only creates a single `CompanyData` instance. So the list it returns only has one element.

Answer (score 1):

The method `setAll(...)` replaces all the elements currently in the list with the ones you provide (it "sets them all"). So each time you iterate through your loop, you replace all the elements with the current one. At the end you will just have one element in the table.

An [`ObservableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) is a subtype of the standard [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), so you can call any of the standard list methods. E.g. you can just add each element instead:

```
public  void companyTable() {
   for(CompanyData s: companydataList()){
       companyDataTableView.getItems().add(s);
   }
}
```

Of course, you don't really need to write the loop yourself, you can just add them all:

```
public  void companyTable() {
    companyDataTableView.getItems().addAll(companydataList());
}
```

or, if it's what you need, set them all:

```
public  void companyTable() {
    companyDataTableView.getItems().setAll(companydataList());
}
```

Furthermore, your `companydataList()` method only creates one `CompanyData` instance, and then constantly changes it. Here is your current implementation, with comments explaining what each line you wrote does:

```
private List<CompanyData> companydataList(){

    // create a single instance:
    CompanyData company = new CompanyData("test",9,1);

    // repeatedly change the name of that instance:
    for(String i : sim.getCompanyNames()) {
       company.setPFCompanyName(i);
   }

   // repeatedly change the value of that instance:
   for(int j : sim.getCompanyValues()) {
       company.setPFShareValues(j);
   }

   // create an empty list:
    List<CompanyData> companydata = new ArrayList<>();

    // add one object to the list
    companydata.add(company);

    // return the list containing the single object:
    return companydata;
}
```

You need to create a `CompanyData` instance for each of the `name`/`value` pairs, and add each instance to the list. Assuming `sim.getCompanyNames()` and `sim.getCompanyValues()` return lists (or arrays; I will assume they are lists) of the same length, you need to do something like

```
private List<CompanyData> companydataList(){


   List<String> companyNames = sim.getCompanyNames();
   List<Integer> companyValues = sim.getCompanyValues();

   List<CompanyData> companydata = new ArrayList<>();

   for (int i = 0 ; i < companyNames.size(); i++) {
       String name = companyNames.get(i);
       int value = companyValues.get(i);
       CompanyData company = new CompanyData();
       company.setPFCompanyName(name);
       company.setPFShareValues(value);
       companydata.add(company);
    }
    return companydata;
}
```

Obviously, it would be far more sensible to have `sim`, which I assume is some kind of data accessor, return a `List<CompanyData>` directly in the first place, instead of two different lists for the different properties.

Comment: Issue still occurs

Comment: @Zeionic Yes, your `companydataList()` method only creates one object. See update.

Comment: Thank you so so so much James_D!

Comment: Makes sense - I kept overwriting the object ..Feel bad for not noticing that

Comment: @Zeionic Some unsolicited advice: JavaFX is a moderately advanced framework. I don't really recommend trying to use it until you have understood the basics of Java. How to use basic objects, with get/set methods, and how to use collections, are things you should master before you try to learn a complex framework like this.